# font-awesome-railsでSprockets::FileNotFound エラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsのGemfileにgem font-awesome-railsを追加した後、rails sすると、
`couldn't find file 'font-awesome' with type 'text/css'`とエラーが起きます。

エラーが起きている場所です。
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'pc/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

css描画をpcとspで分けるために`stylesheet_link_tag`に`pc/application`と指定しています。
なので、`*= require font-awesome`をpc/application.cssに追加していますが、このようなエラーが出ます。どうすれば解消するでしょうか。。お力添えをお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

同じようなサンプルアプリを作ってみましたが、特に問題なく動きました。

コードはこちらです。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/font-awesome-sandbox

スクリーンショットはこんな感じです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下の情報を追記してもらえると解決するかもしれません。
一部ではなくできるだけ全体を載せてもらうと助かります。

- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock
- pc/application.css
- pc/application を読み込んでいるlayoutファイル（application.html.erb等）
- エラーのスタックトレース

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。リポジトリを見て、自己解決いたしました！
pc/application.css
にて`*=require font-awesome`を`*=require tree.`の下に書いていたことが原因でありました。